# windows batch: copy files in the loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, move

I have a directory with .txt files. I need to loop over them and perform two tasks: pass the file into Oracle's stored proc and move it into archive directory. For some reason second task does not work for me. What am I missing?

```
REM -----------------------------------------
REM first step changes file extension to .632
REM -----------------------------------------
for /f %%I in ('dir /b \\db01\load\*.txt') do (sqlplus.exe usr/pwd@DB @\\db01\sql\load.sql %%I)
for /f %%I in ('dir /b \\db01\load\*.632') do (move \\file01\archive)
```

Comment: Each filename output from inside the parentheses is assigned to the metavariable `%%I`; you therefore need to provide `%%I` as an argument to the `move` command. Is there a reason for the `for` loop on the second line? Can you not just use `move` with a wildcard? _Enter `move /?` at the Command Prompt for usage information._

Comment: So I could do: `for /f %%I in ('dir /b \\db01\load\*.txt') do (sqlplus.exe usr/pwd@DB @\\db01\sql\load.sql %%I move %%I \\file01\archive)` OR `for /f %%I in ('dir /b \\db01\load\*.txt') do (sqlplus.exe usr/pwd@DB @\\db01\sql\load.sql %%I) move \\db01\load\*.632 \\file01\archive`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of untested examples:

```bat
@Echo Off
PushD "\\db01\load" 2>Nul || Exit /B
For %%A In (*.txt *.632) Do (
    If /I "%%~xA"==".txt" sqlplus usr/pwd@DB @"..\sql\load.sql" "%%A"
    If /I "%%~xA"==".632" If Exist "..\..\file01\archive\" Move /Y "%%A" "..\..\file01\archive" >Nul
)
PopD
```

```bat
@Echo Off
PushD "\\db01\load" 2>Nul || Exit /B
For %%A In (*.txt) Do sqlplus usr/pwd@DB @"..\sql\load.sql" "%%A"
If Exist "*.632" Move /Y "*.632" "..\..\file01\archive" >Nul
PopD
```

*Additionally, depending upon your `sqlplus` command requirements, you may wish to look at the `Start` command usage information, `start /?`*